# How to present logo concepts to a client using Indesign

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign

I'm an amateur graphic designer, however I do know the importance of presentation in any product or service.

I was wondering if there are any preset **Indesign templates or rules of thumb on how to present logo concepts**, including color palette and some identity design.

Comment: There is no 'template' for showing a logo. Typically center the logo on a piece of paper. But each designer does it their own way.

Comment: the reason that I ask is because I've seen some really nicely laid out presentations. My focus is usually on web design and don't need to provide print options. I wasn't sure if there were any go to templates or best practices. Thanks for the thoughts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just as @DA01 mentioned in his comment, there is no common way to present a logo.

However, here are the most common approaches I've met:

1. A logo is simply centred on a sheet of paper.
2. A logo is centred over a white-to-light grey radial gradient which does not bring the background far from white but helps to draw a little bit more focus to the logo.
3. The sheet of paper can be framed or sometimes even filled with a derivative pattern (if your client has ordered a pattern, of course).
4. Apart from that, a logo can be presented together with its possible applications (again, if such work has been agreed upon) - to help client's visual imagination which sometimes can suffer.

Having said that, there is still a need to be aware of the potential issues related to presenting the part of work you haven't been committed to do.

Additionally, if you are presenting several variants of a logo, it's a good practice to number or even name them to help further identification.

Answer (score -2):

Before showing your logo concept to your customer at first you have to ask some question to yourself.

- Is your logo match with the client's business?
- Tell your client what is the hidden message behind your logo, in many cases clients like to work with those designers who don't just design a logo but also convey message out from that logo.
- Come up with more than one design so your customer has a choice to select the best one according to their preference.
- Act like a professional don’t look like a newbie.
- Review your logo again and again.

  [How to Successfully Present Logo Designs to Clients: A Step-by-Step Guide](http://graphicdesignjunction.com/2018/10/how-to-successfully-present-logo-designs-to-clients-a-step-by-step-guide/)!

Comment: that's not what's being asked